# how to use django-userena to test forgot password link

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, django-userena

I am new to django-userena and working on a test case to automate "forgot password" link that gets sent to the email id and don't really know where to start?

I use selenium to automate all of my django tests, however, selenium does not seem to help "Forgot Password" link test and that's when i was told to use django-userena, being new to this, am not able to figure out a way to get started on this

any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the documentation and read through that:
[Here](https://django-selenium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: I already got my selenium tests done, the only problem i have now is to write a test using django-userena  to test "forgot-password" link that gets sent to an email. i am new to django-userena and not sure where to start      @TidusJar